# Is it possible to define ENUM with integer values in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

like `CREATE TYPE complexityType AS ENUM(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: I'm not a typical postgresql user myself, but since the docs say `Enum labels are case sensitive`, seems to imply strings, so maybe those those need to be: `ENUM('1',  '2',  '3')`, which seems [to be ok](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ffa51cb3a4b522c18243b7698ff3914c), but might not be what you want. Perhaps other more regular postgres users here may have more insight.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve with that? A CHECK CONSTRAINT limiting an integer column to just those three values seems a much better approach.